# Node.js Exec not running on Visual Studio Code with MAC

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code prompts this message when running the extension Node.js Exec:

> Running the contributed command: 'extension.miramac.node.exec' failed.

It was running Ok until I changed my terminal shell to **zsh**. Changed to **bash** again but still not working.

Thanks in advance for any kind of help provided.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I noticed that this happened after updating the VSCODE, the solution I found was to install the previous version. It sure will do.

I explain how to install the previous version in this video -> https://youtu.be/jAi3J3gNp6k.

Edit:

Following the recommendations of [Logan Devine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14133230/logan-devine) and [Henry Twist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10082297/henry-twist), follow all the steps I did [in the video] [3](https://youtu.be/jAi3J3gNp6k) for the correct operation:

1 - uninstall the current vscode.
2 - I downloaded the previous version of vscode.
3 - Installed
4 - Disable automatic updating.

I emphasize that this is just a paleative for immediate operation.

Comment: Link only answers aren't helpful if the link breaks. Please provide the information *in your answer* and use links as "More Information:" or sources.

Comment: I realized that the video was not public, I already corrected it! The video is now available.

Comment: My original comment still applies. 
Link only answers aren't helpful if the link breaks. Please provide the information in your answer and use links as "More Information:" or sources.

Comment: Thank you @josias and zhulien. I actually deleted it and started using Code Runner extension. Works fine. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

an alternative if you don't want to downgrade your VSCode.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0NvJhxhivyk
Credits to [Mayk Brito](https://github.com/maykbrito)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Obrigado!